# Why margin auto works for left/right and doesn't for top/bottom?

Tags: html, css, margin

I always wanted to know why I can use margin auto for left/right to horizontally center a div, and not for vertically center. Here I would have liked to vertically center : *div-block-vertical-line* but margin-top and margin-bottom won't work.

```css
.div-block-container {
  width: 2%;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

.div-block-vertical-line {
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 90%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-block-container">
  <div class="div-block-vertical-line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because it was simply specified this way …?

Answer (score 1):

If you check [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin):

> auto
>
> The browser **selects a suitable margin to use.** For example, in
>   certain cases this value can be used to center an element.

So your browser will simply select `0` for top/bottom margin if you use `auto`.

and in [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#normal-block):

> If 'margin-top', or 'margin-bottom' are 'auto', their used value is 0

---

What you are looking for is defined within the [flexbox model](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins):

> Auto margins on flex items have an effect very similar to auto margins
>   in block flow:
>
> During calculations of flex bases and flexible lengths, auto margins
>   are treated as 0.
>
> Prior to alignment via justify-content and align-self, **any positive**
>   **free space is distributed to auto margins in that dimension**.
>
> Overflowing boxes ignore their auto margins and overflow in the end
>   direction

```css
.div-block-container {
  width: 2%;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  display:flex;
}

.div-block-vertical-line {
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 90%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-block-container">
  <div class="div-block-vertical-line"></div>
</div>
```

So there is no particular reason for the *why*. It was simply defined like that and later enhanced when flexbox was introduced.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't use flexbox because it wasn't supported by my users browsers